# Adding a parameter in ArrangoDB

Tags: database, rest, nosql, arangodb

This may be a kind of basic question, but I simply cannot find an answer...

It is tied to ArrangoDB and I'm just learning it, when I try to insert data with POST request (REST API)  I get an error if I add another parameter that is not the "_key" parameter, so the picture below **adds a document successfully** [image]

but when I try to add a parameter it **gives me an error**

[image]

When I add a document inside a web interface it is inserted successfully even if I add more parameters...
[image]

Does anyone know how to insert a document with more parameters into collection? Do I need to define a schema maybe? Thanks in advance for the answers.
d

Comment: Please add the REST-API URI/endpoint you're calling

Comment: The standard http api works here as expected, with 'user' in the created document -- are you perhaps missing the database in your call?  It's not `http://myhost:8529/_api/document/collection`, but `http://myhost:8529/_db/YOURDB/_api/document/collection`.  If you are calling a foxx app you wrote, the JOI-definition of the endpoint you are calling does not allow user as property of documents. Or is there perhaps a json-schema definition attached to the collection?

Comment: The error message clearly originates from a Foxx service. The route does apparently not define a body parameter `user` and thus joi validation fails. JSON schemas on collections aren't validated with joi but taocpp/json. It's perfectly fine to leave out `/_db/YOURDB` in the URL. The default `_system` database will be used in that case.

Comment: API endpoint: https://67e242d438e1.arangodb.cloud:8529/_db/_system/demoapi/uporabniki
and as @CodeManX suggested https://67e242d438e1.arangodb.cloud:8529/demoapi/uporabniki
 works just as well. I don't have validation schema defined and I'm unaware of what JOI is...